# Deleting a tag (/sys)

Tags: support

I created a question (now deleted), and I created a tag for it, [sys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sys). I looked for it before and didn't know it was the same as [sysfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sysfs). I figured out from a comment to my question. The question was about the [sys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sys) in general and I thought it's too broad and closed it down. Now I want to also clean up the [sys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sys) tag, but don't know how.

Or should it stay and be added to [sys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sys)'s synonyms?

Comment: Unused tags are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it), so I think you've done everything you need to do